# Can someone verify this proof about square matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I'm not sure if this notation is unique to my book but I'm just going to write it down anyways:

- The set of all $m \times n$ matrices with entries from a field $F$ is a vector space, and is denoted as $M_{m \times n}(F)$.
- Here, $\oplus$ means that one matrix is the direct sum of the other two.

Also just note that $W_1$ below is just the set of all $m \times n$ upper triangular matrices.

**Proposition**:         In $M_{m \times n}(F)$ define $W_1 = \{ A \in M_{m \times n}(F) \mid A_{ij}=0\space\text{ if }\space i>j \}$ and $W_2 = \{ A \in M_{m \times n}(F) \mid A_{ij}=0 \space\text{ if }\space i \leq j\}$. Then $M_{m \times n}(F) = W_1 \oplus W_2$.

**Proof**: In order to show that the two sets are equal we must show that they are subsets of each other. So we begin by showing that $W_1 + W_2 \subseteq M_{m \times n}(F)$.

Suppose that $A \in W_1 + W_2$, from here we aim to show that $A \in M_{m \times n}(F)$. Then we have $A=B+C$ where $B \in W_1$ and $C \in W_2$. We also have $B_{ij}=0$ when $i > j$ and $C_{ij} = 0$ when $i \leq j$.

The sum of $B_{ij}$ and $C_{ij}$ will depend on whether $i > j$. In either case, it will be $B_{ij}$ or $C_{ij}$ (the other will become $0$), which are both members of $F$. Thus $A_{ij}=B_{ij}+C_{ij}$ will be a member of $F$. Therefore $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with entries from $F$, so $A \in M_{m \times n}(F)$. Thus $W_1 + W_2 \subseteq M_{m \times n}(F)$.

Now we show that $M_{m \times n}(F) \subseteq W_1 + W_2$. We will represent some matrix $A \in M_{m \times n}(F)$ as the sum of two matrices; one upper triangular matrix and one lower triangular matrix. Let $B$ be the matrix where $A_{ij}=B_{ij}$ if $i \leq j$, and $0$ elsewhere. Similarly, let $C$ be the matrix where $A_{ij}=C_{ij}$ if $i > j$, and $0$ elsewhere. Notice that $B \in W_1$ and $C \in W_2$. If $i > j$ then
$$A_{ij} = C_{ij} = 0 + C_{ij} = B_{ij}+C{ij}.$$
Similarly, if $i \leq j$ then
$$A_{ij} = B_{ij}=B_{ij}+0=B_{ij}+C_{ij}.$$
Both of these cases cover all $i,j$ and we see that $A_{ij}=B_{ij}+C_{ij}$ in both. Therefore $A=B+C$. But $B \in W_1$ and $C \in W_2$ so $A \in W_1 + W_2$. Notice that since there exists no matrix $D$ other than $0$ such that $D \in W_1$ and $D \in W_2$, then $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{ 0 \}$. Therefore $M_{m \times n}(F) \subseteq W_1 + W_2$.

Since we have shown that the sets are subsets of each other, then they must be equal. So by definition, $M_{m \times n}(F) = W_1 \oplus W_2$.  QED.

I want some feedback, do some parts feel vague or unclear? Do some parts need further justification? Is this proof too long? Is it even right? etc.

Comment: The proofs sounds and reads good. Only thing that bothers me is that direct sum is appropriate when talking about subspaces, so you probably should show that  those are subspaces of $M_{m \times n}(F).$ Othervies  it's disjoint Minkowski sum.

Comment: Your proof is correct but the proof of the first inclusion is too long. $W_1 + W_2$ is (defined and) contained in $M_{m \times n}(F)$ simply because $W_1$ and $W_2$ were defined as subsets of $M_{m \times n}(F).$

Comment: @TedShifrin I do not understand your comment.